# How to remove graphic from scanned document before passing it to tesserract for OCRing?

Tags: ocr, tesseract

I'm working on OCR project but I don't know how to remove graphics from the scanned document image before passing it to tesserract.
Some scanned documents which I want to remove graphics are below:

http://www.mediafire.com/view/hvmpty2z3cw3vao/IMG_0087.JPG

http://www.mediafire.com/view/1sgy5s2aaj2o8y3/IMG_0086.JPG

Any advice is very appreciate. Many thanks.

Comment: Don't forget to select the answer that worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

As the text area is usually sparse and does not connect each other, you may consider to have a sobel edge detection on the original image and detect the biggest connection area with some threshold to detect the image area.

Meanwhile, as the image is a rectangle area, another way is to have a Hough translation to detect straight line to consist a rectangle with 4 lines. If you go this way, it’s recommended that you zoom the image first to reduce the calculate complexity.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will think about your idea.

Answer (score 1):

You can start by detecting text areas using an algorithm available in [AForge.Net](http://www.aforgenet.com/). See [HorizontalRunLengthSmoothing](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/f61451b0-4f33-9f34-ca89-fb95ca040614.htm) and [VerticalRunLengthSmoothing](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/249b205e-b7e5-5a70-0eef-65efa5e61da8.htm). The algorithm is not very complicated and you can implement easily it using your favorite image processing library. The only constraint is to know approximately the size of the characters in your images.